# Using CvMouseCallback in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

The program would first show the window with webcam feed and the user would define the object to be tracked by drawing a square/rectangle on it. After that, a new window would appear showing the tracked object.

I mainly got the code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/20180073/3.

It works well in the console so. I tried using Qt GUI since I need to use qt GUI because I want to add some features that include push buttons, dialogs, etc. but when I  did, it says:

error: cannot convert 'Calibrate::mouseHandler' from type 'void (Calibrate::)(int, int, int, int, void*)' to type 'CvMouseCallback {aka void (**attribute**((**cdecl**)) *)(int, int, int, int, void*)}'
         {cvSetMouseCallback("image",mouseHandler,&mouseParam);}

The error is found in this line:
{cvSetMouseCallback("image",mouseHandler,&mouseParam);}

The MouseCallback function is found here:

```
    ///------- MouseCallback function ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param)
{
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && !drag)
    {
        /// left button clicked. ROI selection begins
        point1 = Point(x, y);
        drag = 1;
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && drag)
    {
        /// mouse dragged. ROI being selected
        Mat img1 = img.clone();
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rectangle(img1, point1, point2, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 3, 8, 0);
        imshow("image", img1);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP && drag)
    {
        point2 = Point(x, y);
        rect = Rect(point1.x, point1.y, x - point1.x, y - point1.y);
        drag = 0;
        roiImg = img(rect);
        roiImg.copyTo(mytemplate);
//  imshow("MOUSE roiImg", roiImg); waitKey(0);
    }

    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        /// ROI selected
        select_flag = 1;
       drag = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is way too much code to skim through. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) compliant small example reproducing the issue.

Comment: I don't know the OpenCV framework but I do know that there is often a difficulty using class member functions as callback functions because of the difference in calling conventions. I would suggest keeping the mouse handler you have but use it for collecting the necessary data and posting a custom `QEvent` (eg. OpenCVEvent) back to event queue and having your `Calibrate` class pick the event up in it's `event()` function.

Answer (score 0):

cv::setMouseCallback (and oh, please use the c++ api, not the old c-one) expects a free (non-class member) function as callback.

so, there's 2 ways to handle this:

- make it static (you can't use the 'this' pointer or any class members then )
- redirect to a static function, and call your member function from there:

  class Calibrate {

  ```
  void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param) 
  {
      // this is your member-function shown above.
  }

  static void mouseWrapper(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param) 
  {
      Calibrate * cal = (Calibrate*)param; // cast back to 'this'
      // now call your member-function.
      cal->mouseHandler(event, x, y,flags, 0) ;
  }

  void init()
  {
      // call the wrapper function instead, and
      // pass this pointer for later redirection
      cv::setMouseHandler("image",mouseWrapper,this); 
  }
  ```

  };

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it didn't work. I'm not sure I get all of it. It says `'setMouseHandler' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: ooh, my bad. the cv:: namespace was missing, it's cv::setMouseHandler (or add : `using namespace cv;` after the headers.)

Comment: I already have `using namespace cv` in my program. Maybe there really is something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using c++ API. So maybe you have to change which header to include. 
The function you should use is setMouseCallback(const String& winname, MouseCallback onMouse, void* userdata = 0).
This is declared in opencv2/highgui.hpp.

Then the "static" solution provided by @berak should work.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to *@berak*'s method, just make a little change and it would work.

Instead of coding `cv::setMouseHandler("image",mouseWrapper,this);`, change it to `cv::setMouseCallback`. There is no such function called `setMouseHandler` in OpenCV, so it definitely hasn't been declared.

And don't forget to declare the function in your header. (Only `mouseHandler`)

These are my code, take a look:

```
void MainWindow::mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param)
{
    // this is your member-function shown above.
}

void mouseWrapper(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void *param)
{
    MainWindow * cal = (MainWindow*)param; // cast back to 'this'
    // now call your member-function.
    cal->mouseHandler(event, x, y,flags, 0) ;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    setMouseCallback("image", mouseWrapper, this);
}
```

Hope it would help!